# Python нужно сравнивать рост относительно "зарплаты" предыдущего месяца

Tags: python

Помогите,пожалуйста с задачей. Пользователь вводит десять чисел. Напишите программу, которая проверяет, упорядочены ли они по возрастанию.Если был хоть 1 случай, когда зп падала относительно прошлого месяца, то это говорит о том, что она не росла и нужно печатать соответствующее сообщение.
У меня такой код вышел. Но никак не додумаюсь чтобы выводила,если зп падала.

```
curr = 0
for month in range(11):
  prev = int(input('Введите зарплату: '))
  if curr == 0:
    curr = prev
    continue
if prev > curr:
  print('Зарплата увеличилась ')
elif prev == curr:
  print('Зарплата не изменилась')
else:
  print('Зарплата уменьшилась')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вам нужно научиться проводить элементарную отладку. Вставляйте вывод переменных в разные места кода, чтобы иметь представление о том, что происходит. Это помогло бы вам узнать, например, что переменная curr в вашем когда всегда равна 0.  И много других интересных вещей.

Answer (score 1):

по условию задачи вам надо так делать:

```
prev = -1

for month in range(10):
  curr = int(input(f'Введите зарплату за месяц №{month + 1}: '))

  if curr < prev:
    print('Зарплата уменьшилась')
    break

  prev = curr
else:
  print('Зарплата НЕ уменьшилась')
```

а у вас сравнение выполняется только первого и самого последнего элементов - это неправильно

P.S.

можно также реализовать такой подход (если заплаты вводить в одну строчку через пробел):

```
months = (list(map(int, input().split())) + [0] * 10)[:10]

print("зарплата уменьшалась" if months != sorted(months) else "зарплата не уменьшалась")
```

Comment: Почему везде 11 если по условию задачи "пользователь вводит 10 чисел"?

Comment: согласен, замените на 10

Comment: да, просто из кода автора взял не подумав :) заменил